# cudaFreeHost error on memory successfully allocated with cudaHostAlloc

Tags: c++, cuda, pinned-memory

I have a function which allocates as much pinned host memory as possible using `cudaHostAlloc`, then frees the memory using `cudaFreeHost`.  We have used this code for about 7 years without issue.  Recently one of our developers is consistently erroring at the `cudaFreeHost` call *for a memory pointer that was successfully allocated*.  The error returned by `cudaFreeHost` is `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation`.  It occurs after allocating approximately 15 GiB of pinned memory.

My question is: can a `cudaFreeHost` call error for a pointer returned from a successful `cudaHostAlloc` call?

Or alternatively, what is the bug in the minimum reproducible example code below, or some other misunderstanding?

The error only occurs on **Windows OS** with **3000 series GPUs** (RTX 3060 specifically) and **monitors connected to the GPU**.  All three of those conditions must be met.  Furthermore, every time the error occurs, the Windows Event Log contains:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event:
\Device\000000b5
Error occurred on GPUID: 100
```

The developer made the issue go away by increasing the pagefile size of the OS.  From 6 GiB (automatic) to 8 GiB (manual).  The RTX 3060 on that machine has 12 GiB of GPU RAM.  The PC has 32 GiB of physical RAM.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

size_t MeasureMaxPinnedMemory() {

    size_t maxBytes = 128llu * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;// test up to 128 GiB

    size_t incBytes = 64llu * 1024 * 1024;// 64 MiB chunks

    std::vector<void*> pointers;
    pointers.reserve(maxBytes / incBytes);

    size_t bytes = 0;

    while (bytes < maxBytes) {

        void* ptr;
        cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaHostAlloc(&ptr, incBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault);

        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {

            if (cudaStatus != cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)
                throw std::runtime_error("MeasureMaxPinnedMemory encountered unexpected CUDA error code");

            cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError(); //Clears the cudaHostAlloc error;

            if (cudaStatus != cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)
                throw std::runtime_error("MeasureMaxPinnedMemory encountered unexpected CUDA error code");

            cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError(); //CUDA error state should be zero now

            if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
                throw std::runtime_error("MeasureMaxPinnedMemory could not reset CUDA error state");

            break;
        }

        pointers.push_back(ptr);
        bytes += incBytes;
    }

    for (auto const& p : pointers) {
        cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaFreeHost(p);
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
            throw std::runtime_error("MeasureMaxPinnedMemory failed to free memory");
    }

    return bytes;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try{
        auto bytes = MeasureMaxPinnedMemory();
        std::cout << "Max Pinned Memory: " << bytes << "\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << " \nPress any key to continue\n";
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add details as of which error is / was returned by `cudaFreeHost`? Thanks!

Comment: "allocates as much pinned host memory as possible" [conventional wisdom](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Page-Locked-Host-Memory-Data-Transfer/) is that allocating too much pinned memory can lead to system instability.  There isn't any warning  to indicate that you have gone past the danger point.  From my perspective "allocating as much pinned memory as possible" is never something I would advocate to CUDA developers. You should be judicious and not back the OS into a corner.  Relatedly, it might be important to know the physical memory size in the system where your code fails.

Comment: @Robert Crovella.  I fully agree.  But I would like to focus on whether the example code is flawed from an API perspective, not a design perspective.  I'm particularly disturbed by the cudaFreeHost error; I would not think this is possible.

Comment: FWIW, I tried it on a CentOS7 system with GTX1660 and 8GB, CUDA 12.1, and there was no issue.  Program exits normally reporting a max of ~7.3GB of pinned memory available.    I tried it unmodified on another Ubuntu system with 512GB of memory, and it reports ~128GB of pinned memory available, no issue. When I modified the test to go up to a max of 512GB, then on that 512GB system, the test ran "forever" and the system became unstable.  By that I mean that in another console, the `ls` command would never complete or return.  So I think this is an unwise endeavor.  Good luck!